# Python Regular Expression; replacing a portion of match

Tags: python, regex

How would I limit match/replacement the leading zeros in e004_n07?  However, if either term contains all zeros, then I need to retain one zero in the term (see example below). For the input string, there will always be 3 digits in the first value and 2 digits in the second value.

Example input and output

```
e004_n07 #e4_n7
e020_n50 #e20_n50
e000_n00 #e0_n0
```

Can this be accomplished with re.sub alone, or do I need to use re.search/re.match?

Comment: why not skip using regex and use `str.replace('0','')`

Comment: Do you want to replace all zeros or just leading zeros? How do you want to handle e.g. `e020_n50`?

Comment: What are the rules? Replace zeros after letters? Use `re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])0+', r'\1', s)`

Comment: Sorry, just leading zeros. e020_n50 should become e20_n50.

Comment: Googlesauces are; `lookahead` and `lookbehind`

Comment: @SSH Please edit the question to indicate that you only care about removing the leading zeros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to only remove zeros after letters, you may use:

```
([a-zA-Z])0+
```

Replace with `\1` backreference. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI2vF0/1).

The `([a-zA-Z])` will capture a letter and `0+` will match 1 or more zeros.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/n1BaaV):

```
import re
s = 'e004_n07'
res = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])0+', r'\1', s)
print(res)
```

Note that [**`re.sub`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) will find and replace all non-overlapping matches (will perform a global search and replace). If there is no match, the string will be returned as is, without modifications. So, there is no need using additional `re.match`/`re.search`.

**UDPATE**

To keep 1 zero if the numbers only contain zeros, you may use

```
import re
s = ['e004_n07','e000_n00']
res = [re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])0+(\d*)', lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else '0', x) for x in s]
print(res)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/QeFcsL)

Here, `r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])0+(\d*)'` regex matches one or more zeros (`0+`) that are after an ASCII letter (`(?<=[a-zA-Z])`) and then any other digits (0 or more) are captured into Group 1 with `(\d*)`. Then, in the replacement, we check if Group 1 is empty, and if it is empty, we insert `0` (there are only zeros), else, we insert Group 1 contents (the remaining digits after the first leading zeros).

Comment: Thanks! One follow-up: I also need to handle the special case, 'e000_n00', where both terms contain all zeros.  In this case, I would like the output to be: 'e0_n0'.  So the rule would be modified as follows: Remove leading zeros in both terms EXCEPT for the case where either term contains all zeros.  In this case, do not remove the final zero.

I have found that the following expression seems to work, but would like to know if it is an appropriate solution:
res = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])0{2}|([_][a-zA-Z])0{1}, r'\1\2', s)

Comment: It is interesting: are you using Python 3.5? Your `([a-zA-Z])0{2}|([_][a-zA-Z])0{1}` will not work with `e010_n01` and it won't work with Python versions before 3.5.

Comment: In Python 3.5, you can also use `re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])(?=((0)+))\2(?!\d)|([a-zA-Z])0+(\d*)', r'\1\3\4\5', s)`, but I would not recommend that monstrous pattern. In earlier Python versions you will get an *unmatched group* error.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `re.sub` if your replacement is so simple - simply use `str.replace`:

```
s = 'e004_n07'
s.replace('0', '') # => 'e4_n7'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is that you MUST use `regex`, then below is your regex pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'e004_n07'
>>> line = re.sub(r"0", "", s)
>>> line
'e4_n7'
```

However it is recommended not to use regex when there is other efficient way to perform the same opertaion, i.e. using `replace` function

```
>>> line = s.replace('0', '')
>>> line
'e4_n7'
```

Answer (score 0):

***edit:** Don't let anybody talk you out of validating the format of the fixed data. If that's what you need, don't settle for something overly simple .*

Not very pretty, but in a situation that seems fixed, you can just
set all the permutations, then blindly capture the good parts,
leave out the zero's then substitute it all back.

Find `([a-z])(?:([1-9][0-9][0-9])|0([1-9][0-9])|00([1-9]))(_[a-z])(?:([1-9][0-9])|0([1-9]))`

Replace `$1$2$3$4$5$6$7`

Expanded

```
 ( [a-z] )                     # (1)
 (?:
      ( [1-9] [0-9] [0-9] )         # (2)
   |  
      0
      ( [1-9] [0-9] )               # (3)
   |  
      00
      ( [1-9] )                     # (4)
 )
 ( _ [a-z] )                   # (5)
 (?:
      ( [1-9] [0-9] )               # (6)
   |  
      0
      ( [1-9] )                     # (7)
 )
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 8 ) 
e004_n07  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 1 ) 
e  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 3 , len 1 ) 
4  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 4 , len 2 ) 
_n  
 **  Grp 6 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 7 , len 1 ) 
7
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Let's see, it validates the entire paired value and does it in one pass. Let's check the performance Regex1:   ([a-zA-Z])0+
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   10
Elapsed Time:    0.40 s,   404.17 ms,   404168 µs


Regex2:   ([a-z])(?:([1-9][0-9][0-9])|0([1-9][0-9])|00([1-9]))(_[a-z])(?:([1-9][0-9])|0([1-9]))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    0.47 s,   465.32 ms,   465317 µs